# Authentication with specific subdomains

Tags: nginx, authentication, subdomain

Basically I'm trying to enable the authentication module when accessing to a specific part of a subdomain, which are `dev.domain.com` and `pma.domain.com`, they both must have the authentication module loaded. I can't seem to figure why my nginx configuration file isn't working.

In the second server block you can see the `pma` and `dev` with the authentication module, when I access to `pma.domain.com` or `dev.domain.com`, I don't see the authentication module showing from my browser, nor any error logs stored.

Anyway, I just need a fix to enable the authentication on them two subdomains, not an entire rewrite of my nginx configuration file.

```
server {

    server_name domain.com;

    root            /var/www/domain.com/www;
    index           index.php index.htm index.html;
    error_page      404 /404.html;
    error_page      500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    access_log      /var/www/domain.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log       /var/www/domain.com/logs/errors.log;

    error_page 404  /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ 
    {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domain.com/www$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

server {

    server_name ~^(.+)\.domain\.com$;

    set $file_path $1;

    root            /var/www/domain.com/www/$file_path;
    index           index.html index.php;

    access_log      /var/www/domain.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log       /var/www/domain.com/logs/errors.log;

    location /
    {
        try_files $uri /$uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ pma
    {
        auth_basic            "Website development";
        auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/domain.com/www/dev/authfile;
    }

    location ~ dev
    {
        auth_basic            "Website development";
        auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/domain.com/www/dev/authfile;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ 
    {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domain.com/www$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

However, you need to split this two domains in separate server blocks and leave wildcard substitution for others, or try to use workaround below.

1.
"location" directive works with URI only, not with host header

2.
And if you try to do something like

```
if ($host ~ "(dev|pma).example.com" ) {
        auth_basic            "Website development";
        auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/domain.com/www/dev/authfile;
}
```

then you will get a

> error nginx: [emerg] "auth_basic" directive is not allowed here
>   in.....

because auth_basic directive is unconditional

**workaround** (*not well tested*):

```
    if ($host ~ "(dev|pma).example.com" ) {
        return 555;
    }

    error_page 555 = @auth;

    location @auth {
        auth_basic            "Website development";
        auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/domain.com/www/dev/authfile;
        try_files $uri /$uri /index.php?$args;
    }
```

Comment: I get this error when restarting nginx `Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "if($host"`

Comment: add a space symbol between "if" and "($host"

Comment: Here's a weird thing, when I access the subdomains, the page constantly loads for a long time then shows a blank page after that. Any reason why?

Comment: Well... anything...?

Comment: At least give me a response.

Comment: Hey! At least help when you can!

Comment: You'll lose the bounty if you don't answer.

Comment: You should use recursive_error_pages on; For ghloogh solution.

Answer (score 6):

A way simpler solution is either use map

```
map $http_host $auth_type {
    default "off";
    example.domain.tld "Restricted";
}

server {
    auth_basic $auth_type;
}
```

*Or*

As of `nginx 1.5.4+` the auth module:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html

Comment: Nice. I had to add hostnames; at the top of the map to be able to use wildcard matching

Comment: Depends on who is taking over your dns.